# How to configure DNS If I use the plugin yet-another-multi-site-manager?

Tags: multisite, domain

I just configured yet-another-multi-site-manager and I can able to use internal sub-domains like **1.domain.com and 2.domain.com** as alternate domains .I can able to create sub-sites on those domains successfully like **try.1.domain.com**  .

But Unfortunately when I set external domain(Primary domain Registered some where else) the sub-site's URL showing error page..

Example:
**3.domain.com** is addon domain pointing to my multi-site installation folder .A sub-site created under it is **try.3.domain.com** .This sub-site's URL showing error page.

Actually I am pointing that external domain pointing to Numeric IP(My hosting is shared hosting) address of my multisite domain.Later adding that domain as an addon pointing to my Multisite installation folder .

Does any one have Idea on this?I think that I have wrongly configured the DNS of Addon domain .

**Update:**
Now I am able to create sub-sites using the additional domains .But the problem is when logging into the sub-sites created on these domains .The login pages are again redirecting to login form and the loop continues .I am even unable to edit the sites using the option "Backend" on admin panel .

**Update 2:**
The code inside the yamm-signup.php page and yet-another-multi-site-manager.php  are not updated as per the updated new version 3.1 .The plugin is prepared for wpmu not updated for a long while .

Comment: I think that am missing something with DNS configuration .

Answer (score 2):

You will have to get a dedicated IP to make things simpler.

It works exactly like the domain mapping plugin, with the exception that you need to create a wildcard A record.

Unlike domain mapping, you can't get around the dedicated IP requirement by parking the domain, as parking will only cover the main 3.domain.com, and not any non existing *.3.mydomain.com subdomains. cPanel does not seem to support this via their admin interface. It is however possible to manually edit your apache conf file and add them to the ServerAlias line in your virtualhost: `ServerAlias 3.domain.com *.3.domain.com`

Comment: sorich87 is right, you have to setup an A record for each child domain and configure virtualhost in httpd. sorich87 I would upvote you but I am new to stackexchange. :] Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you using but I can confirm you that all you need is the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping) plugin.

I'm using it with multiple domains and it works perfectly. All you have is to add the domains.

If all your DNS domains are resolved with the same IP as the one on the WP server, you do not have a DNS configuration issue.

2nd, check that Apache is properly configured to answer to all these domains.

Comment: I am using that domain mapping plugin for domain mapping.But this question is about configuring multiple domains using Yet Another Multi-Site Manager .SO my users have the choice to choose the extension they wish .

Comment: I am using that domain mapping plugin for domain mapping already.But this question is about configuring multiple domains using Yet Another Multi-Site Manager .SO my users would have a choice to choose the extension they wish while sign up .Ex:name.domain1.com ,name.domain2.com ,name.domain3.com